# Battleships game - keeping track of ships

Tags: c++, oop

I've searched my best on here in order to find the answer to my question but there's either no results or I'm not searching the right thing, but anyway...

The battleships game I need to create has to have: 1 Aircraft Carrier of length 5, 2 battleships of length 4, 3 destroyers of length 3 and 4 submarines of length 2.

I have a ship class which holds data such as the id, name, x, y and direction.

I then have a board class which then needs to instantiate all these ships. I'm doing this by making a vector of type Ship and pushing ship objects onto that.

However each ship objects needs to store all the x and y values of that ship and I'm stuck on how to do that. I wanted to post code but it's non functional and looks messy at the moment which is probably not beneficial to anyone. However if necessary I can write the skeleton again and post it up here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have x, y and direction then the points of the ship can be calculated from it's size

Comment: Even better, you don't need to calculate all of the individual points, you can use range comparisons instead, like `if (guess.x >= ship.x) && (guess.x < (ship.x+ship.size))` when the direction is facing right from `ship.x`.

Comment: Yep that's what I was thinking @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0):

Each ship could just have a `vector<Point>` inside. Checking for hit could be then:

```
Point guess;
for (auto& ship : ships) {
    for (auto& point : ship.points) {
        if (point == guess) 
           // hit
    }
}
```

That would make sense if you are aiming for a version where you need to hit the ship once in each of its parts.

The inner loop can also be easily changed to `std::find`, making it arguably more clear.

Comment: This sounds good! Am I being stupid though or is Point a class in C++ or something I would have to implement myself?

Comment: There's an std complex type, but I'd hack something for that or use glm probably.